# RecyclerView scroll is messed up (in the presence of big Bitmaps)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[image: GIF of what's happening to my RecyclerView]

P.S. the big chat bubbles at the bottom of the screen are an image (just like when you send an image via WhatsApp and other messaging apps)

I'm making a simple chatting app. The problem is, whenever I scroll to the top, the view comes back to the very bottom. Here's my OnBindViewHolder code (some parts are omitted because it's too long):

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MessageViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
    final ChatMessages c = messageList.get(i);
    final String from_user = c.getFrom();
    String message_type = c.getType();

    if (currentUser.equals(from_user)) {
        viewHolder.mydisplayName.setText(dummyright);
    } else {
        viewHolder.displayName.setText(dummyleft);
    }
            if (currentUser.equals(from_user)) {
        leftLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        rightLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        person = "leftLayout";
    } else {
        leftLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        rightLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        person = "rightLayout";
    }

    if (message_type.equals("text")) {
        //set visibility of TextViews and other elements according to which user is sending the message (left/right)
    } else if (message_type.equals("image")) {
        if (person.equals("leftLayout")) {
            viewHolder.mymessageText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewHolder.myview_data.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewHolder.mymessageImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Cursor cursor = null;
            final String tempUri = c.getDownload_link();
            filename = null;

            byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(c.getMessage(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
            options.inSampleSize=512;
            decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length,options);

            try {
                Glide.with(viewHolder.mymessageImage.getContext())
                        .asBitmap()
                        .load(decodedString)
                        .thumbnail(0.5f)
                        .into(viewHolder.mymessageImage);
                decodedString=null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("chat image right", e.getMessage());
            }

            File file = null;
            if (tempUri != null) {
                file = new File(tempUri);
                String path = file.getAbsolutePath();

                if (tempUri.startsWith("content://")) {
                    try {
                        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse(c.getDownload_link()), null, null, null, null);
                        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            filename = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        }
                    } finally {
                        cursor.close();
                    }
                } else if (tempUri.startsWith("file://")) {
                    filename = file.getName();
                }

                viewHolder.mymessageImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder;
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert);
                        } else {
                            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                        }
                        builder.setTitle("Save Image")
                                .setMessage("Do you want to save this image?")
                                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        // continue with delete
                                        startSaveImageToGallery();
                                    }
                                })
                                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        // do nothing
                                    }
                                })
                                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                                .show();
                    }
                });
            } else {
            }

        } else if (person.equals("rightLayout")) {
           //same as above but for the right layout
        }
    } 
}
```

I've read a lot of questions about this issue and some of the answers said that it's caused by setting visibility inside onBindViewHolder. I don't know where else I would set them because my layouts' visibility are dependent on some data (in this case, who's sending the chats).

Edit: I've just tried my app several times and apparently it only jumps to the bottom when there are pictures being sent, especially when they're 600KB or more in size. I'm loading my images with Glide, they are stored in Base64 and converted to compressed Bitmaps. Do these images cause the messed up scrolling?

Comment: Instead of playing on visibility you could have multiple viewholders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.If the ImageView is `wrap_content`,set a fixed size value for it.

2.If the `OnBindViewHolder` method has other asyn operations which are relatived to the UI,deal with them before `setData`.

3.Check your code,if there are methods such as `scroll to`

Comment: setting a fixed size value for the ImageView actually fix the problem. Thank you @motee

Comment: It's my pleasure!

Comment: In my case, set fixed size value of imageview don`t fix my problem, now the scenario is that when i share a post (media image) with another user and soft keyboard open when user send next message the same bubble appear (ImageView bubble) appear for the last sent text message, but when i pressed back button to hide soft keyboard then imageview row item automatically hide and text row item shown.